# How to Change MU/BuddyPress Group Blog New Installation Defaults

Tags: plugins, buddypress, child-theme

I am trying to work with a Multisite install of WordPress and modify the default "child" blogs in the network.  The details are:

-I have a main site built on Commons in a Box ([CBOX](http://commonsinabox.org/)) which is a modified version of BuddyPress which allows users to register and then create groups.

-If a user creates a group, he/she has the option of creating a "[group blog](http://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-groupblog/)" (It is a BuddyPress orientated plugin) that is tied to the group and is essentially a new WordPress blog within the the main site.

---

!!!The Problem!!!

-I want the default installation to be different than the normal WordPress "hello world" post, sample page, etc.

Mainly, I would like to minimize most of the admin menu options so that users do not see them, i.e. more user friendly and less work if something goes wrong.

---

I already have the ability to set the default theme for the new installations and so I was wondering if I should use a plugin for this or a child theme or something else?

I saw this plugin, [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/), and was wondering if I could use it some way as a default plugin for a new install, with all of the options set and the plugin menu hidden.

I am also trying to use [CommentPress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/commentpress-core/) for the new sites which has a built-in theme as well as other quirks.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry everyone, the bounty was intended for [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/multisite-mu-sub-directory-404-problem-with-modified-permalink-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Plugin Adminimize did not work for me since I was using a multisite (MU) install.  Instead I used the functions.php file of my theme to write custom code which accessed the [remove node](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_node) function in WordPress. Custom CSS finished the job.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.